# How to tell cmake to find SDL library where I want in project?

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, sdl-2, clion

I wasted hours to find best way of installing SDL2 library and linking it to my project on Windows with cmake because I'm new on it. The guide that works for me: https://blog.ahmadz.ai/sdl2-for-clion-and-cmake/. It tells to use third party module FindSDL2.cmake, put SDL library itself in project root and write this cmake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23)
project(game)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/modules)
set(SDL2_PATH "SDL2-2.26.4/x86_64-w64-mingw32")

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR})

add_executable(game src/main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(game ${SDL2_LIBRARY})
```

But I can't get the line

```
set(SDL2_PATH "SDL2-2.26.4\\x86_64-w64-mingw32")
```

because nothing changes when I remove it. Looks like it tells the FindSDL2.cmake module where to find SDL but actually it doesn't.

So I wanted to **change position of SDL from project root to** ***lib* folder in the project**. The relative path from root to x86_64-w64-mingw32 folder looks like "libs/SDL2-2.26.4/x86_64-w64-mingw32" so I changed that line to

```
set(SDL2_PATH "libs/SDL2-2.26.4/x86_64-w64-mingw32")
```

and get this error:

```
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2022.2.4\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" --build C:\Users\helko\CLionProjects\game\cmake-build-debug --target game -j 9
ninja: error: '../SDL2-2.26.4/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libSDL2main.a', needed by 'game.exe', missing and no known rule to make it
```

**How can I find this lib with cmake in not root folder of the project?**